# PHP array value to variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, count

I'm using the following piece of code to count the number of `locations` from a table:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT location FROM table ORDER BY location");

$aloc_list = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {$aloc_list[] = $row['location'];
        }

print_r(array_count_values($aloc_list));
```

Which gives me the following array:

```
Array
(
    [CANADA] => 106
    [USA] => 547
    [MEXICO] => 93
    [GREAT_BRITAIN] => 111
    [EASTERN_EUROPE] => 227
    [RUSSIA] => 405
    [CHINA] => 341
    [INDIA] => 253
)
```

I have tried to 'extract' the array values and put them in a variable but nothing seems to work:

```
$canada = $aloc_list[0];
$canada = $aloc_list['CANADA'];
$canada = $aloc_list[0]['CANADA'];
$canada = $aloc_list[0];
```

I want to end up with a variable called `$canada` equal to 106, a variable called `$usa` equal to 547, etc.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You can use MySQL's aggregate `COUNT(col)` function given we're working with integers. There are other ways also.

Comment: `$canada = $aloc_list['CANADA'];` should work, as long as you do `$aloc_list = array_count_values($aloc_list);`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton nope, check the `print_r(array_count_values($aloc_list));`.

Comment: @Cid Updated my comment. It only doesn't work because OP isn't setting `array_count_values` to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to select the mentioned values from the original `$aloc_list` array - but they don't directly exist in there. They're the result of the call to `array_count_values($aloc_list)` - this produces a new array, and you need to read from that instead.

For example:

```
$counts = array_count_values($aloc_list);
$canada = $counts['CANADA'];
echo $canada;
```

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya No it isn't, this answer is better because it _explains what's happening_, and what is needing to happen.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change your query, you can store the result of `array_count_values($aloc_list)` and use it to extract the datas. You can use variables variables to generate dynamically variables, but I don't recommend this. You might want to check if variable exists before using it. (`isset()`)

```
$aloc_list_count = array_count_values($aloc_list);
var_dump($aloc_list_count);
/*
Outputs
array (size=8)
    'CANADA' => int 106
    'USA' => int 547
    'MEXICO' => int 93
    'GREAT_BRITAIN' => int 111
    'EASTERN_EUROPE' => int 227
    'RUSSIA' => int 405
    'CHINA' => int 341
    'INDIA' => int 253
*/
foreach ($aloc_list_count AS $key => $value)
    ${strtolower($key)} = $value;
echo $canada; //106
echo $usa;    //547
echo $france; //Notice: Undefined variable: france in...
```

Or you can use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function to achieve that

```
extract($aloc_list_count);
```

Comment: Good idea with the variable variable, but you should apply `strtolower()` to it, OP said they want the variables to be lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

- Instead of doing it at PHP level, you could do it in much more efficient way in MySQL itself, utilizing [Count with Group By](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html).
- Also, you will need to use [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`, because you cant access 'location' key, without getting associative output.
- Also, most important thing is that you should use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) to avoid [SQL Injection related issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)!

Try the following instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT location, COUNT(*) as count_per_location 
        FROM table 
        GROUP BY location 
        ORDER BY location"

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$aloc_list = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
    ${strtolower($row['location']} = $row['count_per_location'];
}
```

Comment: This is certainly the best answer if he doesn't need the query to do something else than counting elements

Answer (score 1):

you are returning the array from array_count_values into the print_r function. try this

```
 $test = array_count_values($aloc_list);
 echo $test['CANADA'];
```

Comment: I don't know of any PHP function called array_print_values

Answer (score 1):

on the line with:

```
print_r(array_count_values($aloc_list));
```

Try this instead:

```
$mergeLocations = array_count_values($aloc_list);
var_dump($mergeLocations['CANADA']);
var_dump($mergeLocations['USA'])
```

By the way, would be smarter to use mysql GROUP BY function for counting locations:

```
SELECT location, count(*) as total FROM table GROUP BY location ORDER BY total DESC
```